# Looking for a 90's shooter-platformer game

Tags: ibm-pc, identify-this-game

Back in the 90's I remember playing a 2d shooter-platformer game on my family's home computer. I sucked at the game, and as far as I remember I never managed to beat the first level.

**The details I can (somewhat) remember**:

- You could play as either a man or a woman
- You where shooting green zombies, but there were aliens as well
- You could obtain a grenade
- There was a boss by the end of the level that was a grey alien (like the classical area 51 grey alien) in a yellow robot suit
- You were fighting the boss on top of either a destroyed skyscraper or a skyscraper that was under construction
- It must have been released in the mid to late 90's
- I remember the graphics as quite colourful and cartoonish
- I believe the background was a city
- It was played on an old Windows computer (i think Windows 95)

**I know it is not these games:**

- Alien Storm
- Duke Nukem
- Rainworm Jim
- Rent a Hero
- Vendetta
- Xenophobe
- Gateworld

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So trough @Tommy's answer I was able to find the game I was looking for. Turns out it was a title called *Zombie Wars*, also known as *Halloween Harry 2*. Essentially it was a sequel to Alien Carnage released in 1996.

[image: Zombie Wars Screenshots]

Comment: can i purchase or download this game somewhere?

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to venture a guess with *Alien Carnage*:

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

It was a shareware title released initially as *Halloween Harry* but later retitled, and the plot revolves around aliens that turn people into zombies. Another notable gameplay element is the character's sometimes jetpack.

It has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Carnage), which reports that at the time of the name change they also switched around the episode order; since Apogee always offered the first episode of a game for free as shareware you should download the demos of both *Halloween Harry* and *Alien Carnage* to get two different episodes for free.